# Signed Java Applet with all-permissions I still get exception

Tags: java, permissions, applet

So I am working on a developing a java applet. The applet is signed with a valid certificate and the manifest file includes "**permissions:all-permissions**", however I get the error message when I try to access the smartcardio. I get the prompt that says that the applet has full access to the system. i.e. not sandboxed

What am I missing here? 
Noting that the issue happens only when I try to connect to the card. I can enumerate the readers and get the events but I can't connect to the card here is the permission check code

```
        Permission CardPermission;
            try {
                Class<?> MyCardPermissionClass = Class.forName("javax.smartcardio.CardPermission");
                Constructor<?> MyCardPermConst = MyCardPermissionClass.getConstructor(String.class, String.class);
                CardPermission = (Permission) MyCardPermConst.newInstance("*", "*");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                console.putln("javax.smartcardio not available: " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
            try {
                securityManager.checkPermission(CardPermission, securityContext);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                console.putln("error " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
```

Here is the manifest

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0.1
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Created-By: Test
Bundle-Name: Test Applet
Bundle-Version: 1.01
Bundle-Date: 2015-06-18 14:19:42 AST
Implementation-Title: BBAB
Implementation-Version: 1.01
Implementation-URL: Test Applet 
Permissions: all-permissions
Main-Class: Testpkg.TestClass
Codebase: *
Application-Name: Test application
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
```

HTML code

```
<script src="file:///someplace//javadeploy.js"></script>
<script>

       var attributes = { id:'TestApplet', archive:'file:///Somplace//Testpkg.jar', code:,
             width:1, height:1} ;
        var parameters = { parameters:'all-permission', codebase_lookup:'false','main-class':'Testpkg.TestClass'};
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.0.1');
 </script>
```

Comment: Provide applet's exact error message.

Comment: access denied ("javax.smartcardio.CardPermission" "*" "*")

Comment: Please provide the implementation of the whole method and the way you are adding it to the HTML/javascript.

Also, paste your manifest.

Comment: I have added the more data I hope this may help